# Spring where is the default /login Endpoint?

Tags: spring, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

I need to know what happens when a POST request is sent to the /login endpoint of a Spring application.

For other endpoints like /oauth/authorize there are "DefaultEndpoint" classes, but I cant seem to find one for /login.

Does anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

No. In OAuth 2.0 You need to obtain the endpoints from the Authorization server provider.

[OpenID Connect provides discovery](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html).